# I will never do it - CE or LE?

Tags: pronoms

How will ***I will never do it*** be in french?

Je le ferai jamais

Or

Je ce ferai jamais

Or no difference?

Answer (score 12):

*Ce* is a determiner, it is an adjective and as such you need a noun to go with it.  What you really want in your sentence is a pronoun, *le* is correct.

- *Je le ferai jamais*.

Note that it is colloquial French, it is used quite a lot in oral language but if you want to go "by the rule" you really need the other part of the negation: *ne*, it all depends what use the sentence is for, in some cases:

→ *Je ne le ferai jamais*.

might be better.

You cannot have *ce* in this sentence because it is an adjective but you could use a demonstrative pronoun, which would be *ça* or *ceci*.

→ *Je ne ferai jamais ça(ceci)*. (*Je ne le ferai jamais, ça*.)

Here's a case where you would use *ce*:

- *Je ne ferai jamais ce travail*.

Comment: Oh, I just forgot to put *ne*, nevermind. In case “i want it» also “je le veux”, right?

Comment: Yes. *Je le veux*.

Comment: +1 pour et merci de avoir fourni la bonne raison grammaticale.

Comment: Note that "Je ne le ferai jamais" is the formal (and written) way of saying that. "Je le ferai jamais" (or even "Je l'ferai jamais" - orally) is used in a more familiar way (e.g. for family/friends/kids) - for what I usually hear at least

Comment: @Rafalon Yes. That can be *je l'ferai jamais* or *j'le ferai jamais* or *je l'f'rai* jamais* or *j'le f'rai jamais*. Depending on the locutor and/or the region, the spoken French shortened version can vary.

Answer (score 1):

Comme indiqué dans les autres réponses, il faut ajouter le "ne" de la négation pour que la phrase soit correcte en français.

J'ajoute cependant une remarque car "I will never do it" pourrait effectivement se traduire de deux manières:

```
Je ne **le** ferai jamais.
```

avec un pronom neutre qui se place devant le verbe ou

```
Je ne ferai jamais **ça**.
```

avec un pronom démonstratif qui se place après le verbe.

Ces deux versions sont correctes, et mettre un peu d'emphase avec :

Je ne le ferai jamais, ça ! / ça, je ne le ferai jamais !

To sum up, you can use "le" or "ça", but make sure that you use "ne" and that it is at the right place.

Comment: I'd say *je ne ferai jamais ça* is rather *I will never do that*.

Answer (score 0):

"Je ne le ferai jamais." *Jamais* doit être accompagné d'une autre négation, as in "Je ne le ferai pas."